# Error: Could not find mapping for model Prisma

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I'm having some problems with a post request and inserting new items into a prisma table. When i send the request, the prisma gives me an error about some error with Mapping, and i won't find anything talking about that , so , i don't know how i can fix it

Error:

> C:\GitHub\Project\BackEnd\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:30904
> throw new Error(`Could not find mapping for model ${model}`);
> ^
> Error: Could not find mapping for model Product
> at PrismaClient._executeRequest (C:\GitHub\Project\BackEnd\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:30904:17)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async PrismaClient._request (C:\GitHub\Project\BackEnd\node_modules@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:30864:16)
> at async createNew(C:\GitHub\Project\BackEnd\src\Controller\ProdutoController.ts:20:25) {
> clientVersion: '4.3.1'
> }
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Prisma Schema:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}


model Product{
    id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
    name        String
    description String
    createDate  String
    datePublish DateTime @default(now())
    type        String
    value       Float
    height      String
    width       String
    length      String
    material    String
    category    String
}
```

function who call prisma create

```
async createNew (req: Request, res: Response){
        const {
            name,           
            description ,      
            createDate,    
            datePublish ,  
            type,           
            value,          
            height,         
            width,        
            length,    
            material,
            category       
        } = req.body

        const product = await prisma.product.create({
            data:{
                name,           
                description ,      
                createDate,    
                datePublish ,  
                type,           
                value,          
                height,         
                width,        
                length,    
                material ,
                category
            },
        })


        
        return res.json({product})
```

**SOLUTION**

I do the migration of schema again and fix the error, prisma said that there were no schema changes, so I believe it was a sync problem with postgre

Comment: I use sudo in prisma db push and problem solved

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it got solved when I ran generate command.

I found that in my case, this error says that, Prisma doesn't have any knowledge of new model on client side, so after pushing and generating schema and Prisma-client gets to know new models.

Answer (score 0):

Would you share more information about this please? I'm not able to overcome this problem.

Comment: So I can't say much about the solution because I just fixed it by luck, but the error appears when I create this new model called "Product", when I try to insert new data into the table, the error appears. And I just fix it by trying to create the prisma migration again. I think on the first migration something causes a problem with the synchronization between postgreSQL (my database) and prisma, for now , is the only thing i know about this problem

Answer (score 0):

have a try with redoing the process :-
step1 : npx prisma generate
step2 : npx prisma db push
step3 : npx prisma studio